# Find $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{|x-1|}{\sqrt{2x^2+2}-(x+1)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{|x-1|}{\sqrt{2x^2+2}-(x+1)}$$

I have multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+2}+(x+1)}{\sqrt{2x^2+2}+(x+1)}$

and got: $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{|x-1|(\sqrt{2x^2+2}+(x+1))}{(2x^2+2)-(x+1)^2}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{|x-1|(\sqrt{2x^2+2}+(x+1))}{(x^2-2x+1)}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{|x-1|(\sqrt{2x^2+2}+(x+1))}{(x-1)^2}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{|x-1|(\sqrt{2x^2+2}+(x+1))}{|x-1|^2}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{(\sqrt{2x^2+2}+(x+1))}{|x-1|}$$

How should I continue?

Comment: that means the limit does not exist.

Comment: wolfram says the answer is $\infty$

Comment: Note that $(x-1)^2 = |x-1|^2$, so you can simplify your expression.

Comment: check the question, you might miss a square on the numerator. Once the square is there, just cancel out $(x-2)^2) and lug in x = 1 for the leftover since there is no siigular point.

Comment: @runaround I cant see why, Wolfram says the limit is $\infty$

Comment: @J.-E.Pin it seems that lophital must be used here

Comment: question is wrong if the expected lomit is finite.

Comment: if limit exist then right and left limits should be equal,check ,both limits:$\lim _{ x\to 1^{ - } } \frac { (\sqrt { 2x^{ 2 }+2 } +(x+1)) }{ 1-x } =\lim _{ x\to 1^{ + } } \frac { (\sqrt { 2x^{ 2 }+2 } +(x+1)) }{ x-1 }  $

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt { 2x^2 + 2} -(x+1).$ Then $f(1) =0,$ and $f(x) > 0$ for $x\ne 1.$ Check that $f'(1) = 0.$ Our expression equals

$$\frac{|x-1|}{f(x)} = \left |\frac{x-1}{f(x)}\right | = \left |\frac{1}{(f(x)-f(1))/(x-1)}\right |.$$

Because $f'(0)=0,$ the denominator on the right $\to 0,$ and since we're taking absolute values, the limit in question is $\infty.$